# Linux identifier removed

Tags: java, linux

I've encountered an interesting problem when running the following piece of Java code:

```
    File.createTempFile("temp.cnt.ent", "cnt.feat.tmp", directory);
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Identifier removed
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1704)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1792)
```

I have never had this problem before and Google doesn't seem to have much for me. The system runs Scientific Linux release 5.8 (Linux 2.6.18-274.3.1.el5 x86_64) and the Java version is

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

The file system (Lustre) has 80TB of free space.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you use a shorter prefix/suffix or different directory (try providing `null`) do you still see the same issue?

Comment: if you run it under strace, do you see a failing system call? Sometimes it's easier to understand the fault at the filesystem layer than to interpret what the JVM exception means.

Comment: I'm running the code that throws the exception under strace at the moment. It doesn't crash every time so it might take a while to reproduce the problem. Stay tuned :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are encountering synchronisation errors between the various instances. Lustre doesn't support file locking, which is probably what `java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively` uses to avoid concurrency woes. (I say "probably" because it doesn't appear to be documented anywhere.)

Without locking it's only a matter of time until file operations interfere with each other. Reducing the number of instances is not a solution because it just makes it less likely to occur.

I believe the solution is to insure that each instance creates files in a different sub-directory

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* that you see an EIDRM. At least the error message looks like that. The IOException wraps an error message from the underlying native libraries.

This is not a real answer to your problem, but maybe a useful hint.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-1075/msgs-1432/index.html has some information an additional pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to having too many instances of the application at a time (each in a separate VM). For some unknown reason the OS refuses to allow the creation of a temp file. Workaround: run less instances.